# Return the second newst record of a group sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like the following:

```
coworker            date
   1             2020.10.30
   1             2019.09.12
   1             2018.05.29
   2             2019.08.07
   3             2020.03.12
   3             2018.06.24
   4             2020.08.16
```

how can I get this:

```
coworker            date
   1             2019.09.12
   2             2019.08.07
   3             2018.06.24
   4             2020.08.16
```

the result should be the second newest record of a coworker if there's more than one,
or the only present

Thanks for any help!

Comment: which sql engine are you using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following with window function `row_number`. Here is the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=44ed2519d252a86a69736b3a3ce807fe).

```
select
    coworker,
    date
from
(
    select
        *,
        row_number() over (partition by coworker order by date) as rn,
        count(*) over (partition by coworker) as ttl
    from myTable
) subq
where (ttl > 1 and rn = ttl - 1) or (ttl = 1 and rn = 1);
```

Output:

```
| coworker | date       |
| -------- | ---------- |
| 1        | 2019-09-12 |
| 2        | 2019-08-07 |
| 3        | 2018-06-24 |
| 4        | 2020-08-16 |
```

Answer (score 0):

`row_number()` function may be helpful:

```
select coworker, date 
from (
    select coworker, date, 
    count(*) over (partition by coworker) as count, 
    row_number() over (partition by coworker order by date desc) as order
    from MyTable
) t
where count = 1 OR (count > 1 and order = 2)
```